# Staking multiple ERC721 NFTs at once

Tags: ethereum, nft, erc721

I have an ERC721NFT contract/collection that is already deployed.
I am asked to stake them which i did by creating a new contract and implementing the onErc721Receive function.
So far so good.
If you send a NFT from the right collection it automatically stakes it and then let you claim your rewards or unstake your NFTs at any time.

However I am asked to implement staking of multiple NFTs at once.
From my understanding since the base contract was a base erc721 contract with no multiple send nor staking it shouldn't be possible.

Is there a way to go around that and stake several NFTs at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You cannot do this in the manner they have described.

If you're someone who found this answer on Google and are currently developing a contract, OpenZeppelin's `Multicall` is a useful helper contract that allows you to perform multiple actions in a single transaction: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/utilities#multicall